# MySQL: multiple selects, multiple joins?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a set of multiple tables (stripped overview):

```
Brand;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | tinyint(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Relations;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id1                | tinyint(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id2                | tinyint(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Country;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | tinyint(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

City;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | tinyint(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Each row has a unique id. Each row in the brand table has a relation with a country and a city. The relations between these tables are stored in the Relations table, so there are two rows in the relations table for each brand row.

I'm trying to get the brand name, country name and city name for a given brand id. I am able to select these relations by individual selects, but my goal is to do it (if possible) in a single query.

I am able to get one of the relations (country), but I want to get the city as well:

```
SELECT Brand.name as brand, Country.name as country
FROM Brand 
LEFT JOIN _relations 
ON Relations.id1 = Brand.id 
INNER JOIN Country 
ON Country.id = Relations.id2 
WHERE Brand.id = '123456';
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| brand     | country     |
+-----------+-------------+
| brandname | countryname |
+-----------+-------------+
```

My goal is to get:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| brand     | country     | city        |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| brandname | countryname | cityname    |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Can anybody help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Join Relations table once again under a different alias.

Something like this:

```
SELECT Brand.name as brand, Country.name as country, City.name as city
FROM Brand 
LEFT JOIN Relations ON Relations.id1 = Brand.id 
INNER JOIN Country ON Country.id = Relations.id2 
LEFT JOIN Relations r2 ON r2.id1 = Brand.id
LEFT JOIN City ON City.id = r2.id2
WHERE Brand.id = '123456';
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you join to relations again and then use that to get City, so something like

```
SELECT Brand.name as brand, Country.name as country, City.Name as City
FROM Brand 
LEFT JOIN _relations relCountry
ON relCountry.id1 = Brand.id 
INNER JOIN Country 
ON Country.id = relCountry.id2 
LEFT JOIN _relations relCity 
ON relCity.id1 = Brand.id 
INNER JOIN City 
ON City.id = relCity.id2
```

Comment: Great, thank you, that was a perfect solution. However I ran into a new issue. What if a city does not exist for a brand. It now returns 0 rows if no city id is found in the relations table. Is there a way to ignore the join and return null or maybe a custom value for the City field? Instead of no result I want to retrieve the brand name, the country name and an empty city field.